# Symfony2 Doctrine2 Many To Many get all entities with their relation entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, inner-join

How to get in controller using one SELECT all entities from one table with his entities from another ?

for example if i have a tables: applications and categories (many to many realation) and i want to get all aplications with their categories using one SELECT. How to do that ? InnerJoin ?

Then i want to set up an array like this:

```
application=>categories

[
  [AppName] => [Category1, Category2, Category3],
  [AppName] => [Category1, Category2]
]
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("name, categories")
            ->from('ComzettaApplicationsBundle:Application', 'name')
            ->innerJoin('ComzettaApplicationsBundle:Application', 'categories');
$applicationsEntity = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But i dont get the idea of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

that query works:

```
    $fields = array('a.Name', 'c.name');
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query
        ->select($fields)
        ->from('ComzettaApplicationsBundle:Application', 'a')
        ->innerJoin('a.categories', 'c');
    $results = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

example of result:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Name' => string 'Google Earth DirectX' (length=20)
      'category' => string 'Nowa1' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Name' => string 'Acrobat Reader 10' (length=17)
      'category' => string 'nowa2' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Name' => string 'Acrobat Reader 10' (length=17)
      'category' => string 'nowa3' (length=8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the repository of the entity, to get its related objects, no need for the join:

```
  $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getRepository('ComzettaApplicationsBundle:Application')->findAll();
```

Comment: In this case each Category entity would perform a separate query to database

Comment: and what next ? do i have to set up some toString method in my repository class ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("application", "category")
            ->from('ComzettaApplicationsBundle:Application', 'application')
            ->join('application.categories', 'category');
$applicationsEntity = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```